# ng-options dont select items from resource

Tags: angularjs

Iam trying to generate a multiple select-element with ng-options and want to preselect some items. I get the preselected items from a database as an array of objects. That is my HTML markup to build the selectable:

```
<select ng-model="currentAppointment.services" ng-options="value.id as value.name group by value.group for value in servicegroups"></select>
```

The currentAppointment.services variable hold the current selected objects. In servicegroups they are all selectable items, which i get from a REST service. The JSON for the servicegroups look like:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Test1"
    "price": 20.0
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Test2"
  }
]
```

And the currentAppointment JSON:

```
{
  "_id": "1001",
  "title" : "test",
  "services": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "Test1"
      "price": 20.0
    }
  ]
}
```

The select-element is created correctly. But the service object with the id 0 is not preselected. I can image that the problem is, that angular compare an normal object against an angularjs Resource-object and so the objects are not equal. Instead the objects should be compared by the id. But how can i achieve that without coding a own directive?

Comment: i found a open corresponding ticket on the angularjs github page: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1302 . May that makes my question a little bit clearer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pre-populate the dropdown list by assigning it with an object, then you need to remove `value.id` from the comprehension expression.

```
<select ng-model="currentAppointment.services" ng-options="value.name group by value.group for value in servicegroups"></select>
```

then do

```
$scope.currentAppointment.services = $scope.servicegroups[0];
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gBgrv/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: But i neet to set an whole object for currentAppointment.services.  somtething like [{ name: "test", id:1}].

Comment: @tschiela Updated the answer. Sorry, I just saw you comment :P